# How to connect Google Play Services when the app is opened?

Tags: java, google-play, google-play-services

```
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.ana_sayfa);


        apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Games.API)
                .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                        Log.e("HATA", "Google Play Oyun servisine bağlanamadı.Lütfen bağlantınızı kontrol ediniz.");
                        finish();
                    }
                }).build();
}
```

I want users to login to google play service when the application is opened.I get the following errors.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Class name: zzf. Start service action: com.google.android.gms.games.service.START. Service Descriptor: com.google.android.gms.games.internal.IGamesService. at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zza.zza(Unknown Source:20) at com.google.android.grns.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzc.zzo(Unknown Source:11) at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzb.handleMessage(Unknown Source:48) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) at android.os.Looperloop(Looperjava:164) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6696) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCallerrun(Zygote.java:240) at com.android.internal.os.Zygotelnit.main(Zygotelnit.java:782)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.I have not added the following code to the manifest file

```
     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
           android:value="@string/app_id" />
```